# trouble with matplotlib pubsub python

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PSPsolver1.py", line 520, in getchain
    Publisher().sendMessage(("show.mainframe"), msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/lib/pubsub/pubsub1    /pub.py", line 750, in sendMessage
    self.__topicTree.sendMessage(aTopic, message, onTopicNeverCreated)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/lib/pubsub/pubsub1/pub.py", line 423, in sendMessage
deliveryCount += node.sendMessage(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/lib/pubsub/pubsub1/pub.py", line 261, in sendMessage
listener(message)
  File "PSPsolver1.py", line 1112, in showFrame
createfigure()
  File "PSPsolver1.py", line 927, in createfigure
x_ax.imshow(xcolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 6749, in imshow
filterrad=filterrad, resample=resample, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py", line 547, in __init__
**kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.set_interpolation(interpolation)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/image.py", line 458, in set_interpolation
raise ValueError('Illegal interpolation string')
 ValueError: Illegal interpolation string
```

I am having trouble with matplotlib
I have a piece of code that is working on one computer, however when I try to run it on another computer it doesn't seem to work and I get this error
Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses

```
x_ax.imshow(xcolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='none')
```

on line 927 of `PSPsolver1.py`. The parameter `interpolation='none'` was introduced sometime between matplotlib version 1.0.1 and 1.2.0.

So my guess is that your two machines are running different versions of matplotlib, and one version is not recent enough.

---

One way to fix the problem is (of course) to update the older version of matplotlib. If that is not an option or you'd rather not do that, then note that [the docs say](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

> If interpolation is 'none', then no interpolation is performed on the
>   Agg, ps and pdf backends. Other backends will fall back to ‘nearest’.

So, if you are not using the `Agg`, `ps` or `pdf` backend, you could change the line to

```
x_ax.imshow(xcolors, cmap=cmap, interpolation='nearest')
```

Of course, if you go this route, there might be other pieces of code that also use newer matplotlib features. They might not be so easy to fix.